# Calendar date is displaying one day ahead

Tags: javascript, html, date, calendar

This is setup on CodePen and is written with JavaScriptand HTML. How can I correct the code so that there is just one dateTime var and it shows today's calendar date?
https://codepen.io/Artomic/pen/LYLXWpb

```
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const dateTime = currentDate.getDate() + "/" +
         (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
         currentDate.getFullYear() + " " +
         currentDate.getHours() + ":" +
         currentDate.getMinutes()
        
        
        var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
       'August','September','October','November','December'];       
        var tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));       
        document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + " " + 
        tomorrow.getDate()+ ", " + tomorrow.getFullYear();
        
        
        const dateTimeB = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
        hour12: false,
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "numeric"
        });
        console.log(dateTimeB)
        
        document.getElementById("dateTimeB").innerHTML=dateTimeB
        
        HTML
        
        <span id="spanDate"></span> 
        <br>
        <span id= "dateTimeB"</span>
        
        <span id="dateTime"></span>
```

Comment: You could just use [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) and write `moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm")`, or Momen't successor [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting) and write `dt.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_MED);`

Comment: You can just add 24 hours to this date, and then use the `toLocaleString` and it will format it for you.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did to fix it  + (1000*3600*24)    Thanks